# containsKey or get not working

Tags: java

I'd like to check if an item is in the inventory (HashMap) of my player (Player).
but this condition, written (in the Player class)

```
this.items.containsKey("beamer")
```

can't compile. I get the error :

```
cannot find symbol - method containsKey(java.lang.String)
```

I tried to import java.lang.String or java.util.HashMap but it does nothing....

Thanks for your help.

edit 1 :
imports :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
```

edit 2 :
I declare items at the start of Player class.
Items is also a class with one attribute, a HashMap with Item as values and String as keys.

```
private Items items = new Items();
```

Comment: post the block of code with imports

Comment: The code you have does not jive with the error you're getting.  Where do you call `get`?

Comment: Show the declaration of the hashmap

Comment: how is `items` declared?, and which line does not compile?

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: sorry it's containsKey, not get

Comment: Post the code where you declare the `items` instance variable.

Comment: First - you don't need to import `java.lang`, that just comes with what you're working with.  Second, reading [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)) suggests to me that you're calling it correctly.  What is the object type of `this.items`?

Comment: Well, what does the `Items` class have to do with `HashMap`? Now post the line `public class Items ...`.

Comment: @Makoto this.items is a HashMap

Comment: I don't see anything that suggests to me (at first blush) that `Items` implements `Map`.  Can you show us the declaration of the `Items` type?

Comment: Dany77, you've just posted the code that spells out clearly that `this.items` is an `Items`!

Comment: @Dany77: prove it by posting its definition. You make it hard for others to help you, because you asume your code is right and the compiler is wrong. The compiler is right, and your code is wrong. To explain you why it's wrong, we need to see it.

Comment: @JB Nizt I don't assume the compiler is wrong!Being novice at programming doesn't mean being idiot... what's wrong with you guys ? i just try to get some help... if you had a bad day, don't put the blame on me.

Comment: @Dany77: glad to hear you didn't assume the compiler was wrong. You were asked thrice in comments to show how Items and the HashMap were declared, and just answered by *"this.items is a HashMap"*, which, finally, proved to be plain wrong. The code doesn't lie. That's why we ask you to post code instead of your interpretation of what the code does.

Comment: ok thanks. i didn't realized that this.items was an Items -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Items is also a class with one attribute, a HashMap

So Items *has* a HashMap, or *contains* a HashMap. Items *is not* a HashMap. So it doesn't have any `containsKey()` method.

You need to add a `containsKey()` method to your Items class, which delegates to the contained Map:

```
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return this.map.containsKey(key);
}
```